# UISegmetnedController with Multiple select

Tags: swift, select, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to make a `SegmentedController` for all weekdays and want to select Multiple (zb: So, Mo, Thu) as shown in the image below.

I have searched but all I can find is in Objective-C and I need a solution for Swift.  Must I make a custom Segmented control or can be make it with the standard `SegmentedController`?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: No need to subclass anything. Check out this [MultiSelectSegmentedControl](https://github.com/yonat/MultiSelectSegmentedControl) on GitHub. It's written in Objective-C, but you can use a bridging header to use it in your swift code. Here's a resource on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Comment: Oh oke good idea thanks.